# Local Notification not working since updating to IOS 8 and Xcode 6

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, xcode6

Has anyone else had problems with local notifications since updating to IOS 8 and Xcode 6? I have my application which was running fine and the `notification.firdate` was set from date picker and working fine, `notification.alertBody`  showed up fine.  Now i've updated it doesn't work.  I've added break points and my firedate has a value stored in it.  Can anyone please help me?

Comment: Make sure you're registering for local notifications (this is mandatory), then implement the proper delegate callbacks.  There are a boat load of changes in iOS8 ... highly recommend you check out the WWDC videos.

Answer (score 68, accepted):

You need to update your code to be able to receive notifications in iOS8. More info [here](http://thecodeninja.tumblr.com/post/89942124085/notifications-in-ios-8-part-1-using-swift-what-is).

Objective-C code:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    if ([UIApplication instancesRespondToSelector:@selector(registerUserNotificationSettings:)]){
    [application registerUserNotificationSettings:[UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:UIUserNotificationTypeAlert|UIUserNotificationTypeBadge|UIUserNotificationTypeSound categories:nil]];
    }
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    return YES;
}
```

Swift Code:

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: NSDictionary?) -> Bool {
//registering for sending user various kinds of notifications
application.registerUserNotificationSettings(UIUserNotificationSettings(forTypes: UIUserNotificationType.Sound|UIUserNotificationType.Alert |UIUserNotificationType.Badge, categories: nil)   
// Override point for customization after application launch.     
return true
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your response.  I've not used swift, will this work in my AppDelegate.m file?

Comment: it worked, was looking at the link you sent.  Thank you for your help

Comment: I've been searching why the notification was failing... this is the answer!

Answer (score 1):

In order to receive Local NSNotification, follow the below steps:

1. Add code into your `appDelegate.h` in `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` method

   ```
   if ([UIApplication instancesRespondToSelector:@selector(registerUserNotificationSettings:)]){
         [application registerUserNotificationSettings:[UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:UIUserNotificationTypeAlert|UIUserNotificationTypeBadge|UIUserNotificationTypeSound categories:nil]];
   }
   ```