# ios9 local notifications do not fire after app update

Tags: ios9, localnotification

Each time the app is starting (
Each time the app is going to background or going to be terminated (didEnterBackground or WillTerminate) I schedule notifications:

1. Cancel existing ones:
   [[UIApplication sharedApplication] cancelAllLocalNotifications];
2. Schedule new ones:
   [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:localNotif];

All worked fine at iOS8 and below. Once iOS9 was introduced I got the following strange behaviour:
If I Install a new app - all works fine, notifications work well
If I update existing app with a new version - notifications stop to be fired.
Does anyone have an idea what is the issue?

Comment: Checkout this link [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11322265/app-lost-control-over-local-notifications-after-being-updated-from-app-store)
or
[this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26101395/local-notification-not-working-since-updating-to-ios-8-and-xcode-6)

Comment: Hi. Have you ever figured this out? Having exactly the same problem with one of my apps.